# Django - MultiChoiceField to_field_name and selected

Tags: python, django, forms, field

I am currently using a MultiChoiceField to represent the corresponding ManyToManyField of my field. It works fine.

I updated my form to use the attribute to_field_name in the form field to change the field used for the values of the inputs and it works fine too.

My issue is that Django, to choose the selected data of the form field, is using the pk and not the field given in to_field_name. Any clue ?

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(...)
    muscles = models.ManyToManyField(Model2, blank=True, null=True,)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    field1 = models.CharField(...)

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    muscles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                queryset=None,
                                to_field_name="field1", required=False,)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['muscles'].queryset = Model2.objects.all()
```

The field of the model is a standard ManyToManyField.

As a example :

In model2, I have these elements : {pk=1, name=name1, field1=3}, {pk=2, name=name2, field1=1}, {pk=3, name=name3, field1=2}.

the generated select is:

```
<option value=3>name1</option>
<option value=1>name2</option>
<option value=2>name3</option>
```

If I select name2, the right pk (ie 2) is saved in database.
When the form is displayed, the selected option is name3 (ie value 2) instead of name1.

I hope I have been clear enough.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Django 1.7.11

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using `to_field_name`? Please show your models. Using a mixture of real variable names (e.g. `muscles`) and made-up names (e.g. `Model2`) makes your code trickier to understand.

Comment: i made the changes. I am using `to_field_name` to change the value of generated inputs as I want field1 to be used in these values instead of pk.

Comment: It looks like Django doesn't support using `to_field_name` for the form field when you are not using it for the model field. The values of the inputs are not visible to the user, so it's not clear why you want to set `to_field_name`.

Comment: Honestly, it works well until django needs to pre-select the selected values stored in database. To sum up, the form field uses well `to_field_name` but the model doesn't use it. And attribute `to_field` for the model does not work

Comment: You're right, you can't use [`to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) for a many-to-many field - you would have to define a custom [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) model.

Comment: that's what i was about to do. Having an intermediate model using `through_fields` should do the trick ?

Comment: in fact to_field doesn't look available for Many to Many fields as i get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'to_field'`

Comment: As I said before, you can't use `to_field` for a many-to-many field. You have to set `to_field` for the *foreign key* in your custom through model.

Comment: oh ok, i'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to achieve what I wanted. As suggested by @Alasdair, I created an intermediary model.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(...)
    muscles = models.ManyToManyField(Model2, blank=True, null=True,)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    field1 = models.CharField(...)

class Model1Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2)

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    muscles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                queryset=None,
                                to_field_name="field1", required=False,)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['muscles'].queryset = Model2.objects.all()
```

Then in the save_model method, I can go through the values of my field and saves them.

The main point to solve my problem was clearly the intermediary model.

Thanks @Alasdair

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you might have hit [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17657#comment:13), which is fixed in Django 1.10.

Comment: Thanks. I need now to schedule the update of my project... :p